# How do I get Dispel Barrier Level 3 in Avernum 2: Crystal Souls?

Tags: avernum-2-crystal-souls

In *Avernum 2: Crystal Souls*, I know that I'm supposed to get Dispel Barrier Level 3 from Pyrn's Barrier Tower, but I've tried everything and I still can't get it.

How do I get Dispel Barrier Level 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh my goodness I found it in the next 5 minutes, and it took me an hour before. I'll just post the screenshot here. You have to activate a switch that's cunningly hidden behind a bookcase so you can't really see it until you mouse over:

[image]